# Windows::Foundation::PropertyValue::CreateUInt64 throws exception

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I'm trying to use CreateUInt64 to create a Platform::Object^, but the code below sometimes throws an exception. I wasn't able to reproduce it personally, but I keep getting reports from our QC testers with this this line on the callstack and the exception in the output. I've looked through documentation of CreateUInt64, but it does not specify what exceptions it could throw - or am I missing something? _strtoui64 documentation says that it will return 0 if no conversion could be performed - so I don't think that's causing the exception. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
Platform::Object^ identifier = Windows::Foundation::PropertyValue::CreateUInt64(_strtoui64(idString, NULL, 10));
```

idString is defined elsewhere as:

```
char idString[255];
```

So I don't see how this could be causing problems here, even it it was empty, or not a number.

The output is:

```
Exception Caught at 0x02AA3BC7 (Unknown exception code: 3765269347)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.